# How to move 'ls' output file to a folder in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have to move latest modified file from a folder to another folder in one unix script file.

am using

```
cd /abc/home/ads/
mv `ls -ltr |tail -1` /abc/home/asd451/Output
```

Comment: That script  is not working, So is there any change to be needed

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not working because you're using `ls -l` and the output is more complicated than a simple filename.

Also, no need of `-r`, just use the first line instead of the last one:

```
mv "$(ls -t | head -1)" /abc/home/asd451/Output
```

I did not find any *good* way to list only files with `ls`, so here is a solution if you only want to move files:

```
mv "$(ls -lt | grep '^-' | head -1 | awk '{ print $9 }')" /abc/home/asd451/Output
```

I use grep to get files only (the output of `ls -l` starts with something like `-rwxr-wr-w` for files, and `drwxr-xr-w` for directories) and print the filename with `awk`.

---

To add the path (I warn you it's becoming dirty):

```
source_path=/abc/home/ads/
mv "$(ls -lt $source_path | grep '^-' | head -1 | awk '{ print "'$source_path/'"$9 }')" /abc/home/asd451/Output
```

Comment: oh, I have a file named `a b c.txt`

Comment: exactly i have to chk for only latest files not folder

Comment: @julienc I misunderstood OP's requirement, I thought he wanted to move multi-files...

Comment: @julienc Can we insert the source path in that script?

Comment: so can you give me alternative way for this script. For complete scenario

Comment: Edited my answer another time.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@\t%f\n' -type f | \
    sort -rn | sed 's|^[^\t]*\t||; q' | \
    xargs -n 1 -d '\n' mv -t /target/dir/
```

Or

```
...
    xargs -n 1 -d '\n' -I{} mv -- '{}' /abc/home/asd451/Output
```